# Instafeed.js does not load any picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, instafeedjs

I am trying to load Instagram image by using **instafeed.js**. I got no pics with this code

```
<script>
    var feed = new Instafeed ({
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'phillyisugly',
    clientId: 'CLIENT ID',
    userId: 'USER ID',
    accessToken: 'ACCESS TOKEN',
});
    feed.run();

</script>
```

But if I use this, I have all pics posted by my Instagram account:

```js
var feed = new Instafeed ({
  get: 'user',
  userID:'USER_ID',
  clientId: 'CLIENT_ID',
  accessToken: 'ACCESS_TOKEN',
  
});
  feed.run();
```

Please spare your time and help me! Many thanks!

Comment: Did you register you application under the new instagram app restrictions? Here is a helpful link https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/issues/345  . Also its a bad idea to reveal your API keys online.

Comment: Thank you Isabel Inc, I have registered. Now, I can get image with get: 'user', but I can't get any piccs with get:'tagged' .  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this piece of code.

```
 var feed = new Instafeed({
  get: 'tagged',
  tagName: 'SomeTag',
  clientId: 'client_id',
  accessToken: 'access_token',
  template: '<li><div><a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}" /></a><h3>{{caption}}</h3></div></li>'
});
    feed.run();
```

Comment: Thank you again :) It does shows the picture , but I can only use the tag which is my account name . My account name is 247cah. The only tag I can use is '247cah'. If I change the tag to 'cats', it does not show anything.

Comment: Thats strange. Any errors in the console or network tab? Can you post the response that instagram is sending back?

Comment: Thank you Isabel Inc, it seems that I need to submit my program for review before I want to see the pictures with any hashtags. I need to have "reading public content" permission. To do this, I need to ask Instagram to review my app. I read in instagram.com/developer/authorization, it notes: "if you plan on asking for extended access such as reading public content, liking, commenting, or managing friendships, you will need to specify these scopes in your authorization request. Note that in order to use these extended permissions, you must first submit your app for review."

Comment: That's good to know. The new instagram review process has broken a lot of libraries. Hope you get your app approved. Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Looks like instagram doesnt allow to see others accounts pictures ... :(